# Swift generic type declaration depending on a previously declared generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I'm building a wrapper on top of a third-party Swift library and I'm stuck in the following situation (simplified, I'll add more details if needed):

```
class Displayer<Item> {

    let itemToBeDisplayed: Item

    init(itemToBeDisplayed: Item) {
        self.itemToBeDisplayed = itemToBeDisplayed
    }

    func display() { print("\(itemToBeDisplayed)") }

}

class EmojiDisplayer<Item>: Displayer<Item> {
    override func display() { print(" \(itemToBeDisplayed)") }
}

class TraditionalDisplayer<Item>: Displayer<Item> {
    override func display() { print("-> \(itemToBeDisplayed)") }
}

class MultipleItemsDisplayer<Item, DisplayerType: Displayer<Item>> {

    var items: [Item] = []

    func displayAll() {
        for item in self.items {
            DisplayerType(itemToBeDisplayed: item).display()
        }
    }

}
```

Basically there's a base `Displayer<GenericType>` class exposed by the library. This class is used to display an object of a generic type in the UI.

I'm creating a generic list of elements (`MultipleItemsDisplayer`) that are going to be displayed using a subclass of `Displayer`. I want to expose that class in a way that the compiler can detect most errors, including trying to use a `Displayer` that doesn't match the type of the elements of displayed list.

My initial approach was defining `MultipleItemsDisplayer` as a generic class with two associated types: `Item`, which defines the type of the elements of displayed list,  and `DisplayerType`, which defines the type used to display each element.

But this cannot be compiled:

> `DisplayerType` is not a subtype of `Displayer<Item>`

`DisplayerType` is not a subtype of `Displayer<Item>` error:

[image]

I'm working with Swift 2.2 at the moment, however this doesn't compile with Swift 3 either (after making initializers required to make it Swift-3-compatible).

I'll rewrite this to use protocols and associated types instead of generic types but I'm curious about this issue: is this a limitation on Swift generics, a compiler bug or does my example not make any sense at all?

Comment: Two possible solutions to this issue could be:



(1.) As third-party library also uses protocols to constraint types, redefine `DisplayerType` to use those protocols and use forced cast in `displayAll` method. Compiler could miss some situations where developers created a type conforming to those protocols but not subclassing `Displayer` class but that is an uncommon situation so might be an acceptable trade-off.



(2.) Define an attribute in `MultipleItemsDisplayer` of type `Displayer<Item>`. Setting a different type as value for it would allow customising `Displayer` subclass used.